# What is PREFIX IN make PREFIX=$HOME/usr/local/OpenBLAS?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, openblas

I am trying to install OpenBLAS.I have created directory

```
 mkdir -p /usr/local/OpenBLAS
```

Then I follow the tutorial instructions:

```
make PREFIX=$HOME/usr/local/OpenBLAS install
make -j 2 -f Makefile.install install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/milenko/OpenBLAS'
Generating openblas_config.h in /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Generating f77blas.h in /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Generating cblas.h in /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Copying LAPACKE header files to /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Copying the static library to /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib
Copying the shared library to /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib
Generating OpenBLASConfig.cmake in /root/usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib/cmake/openblas
Install OK!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/milenko/OpenBLAS'
```

But usr/local/openBLAS is empty!
The new directory is created in /home/m/OpenBLAS/usr/local/.
Should I only export path to bashrc?Other programs will call OpenBLAS in future,this can cause troubles or not?

Comment: You set PREFIX to `$HOME/...`, so it installed in `$HOME/...`.  Apparently your `$HOME` was `/root` at the time.  If you want to install in `/usr/...` use `make PREFIX=/usr/...` (no `$HOME`).

Comment: Just to repeat what @torek already said, `$HOME/usr/local` is a different path than `/usr/local`.  You would `mkdir -p /home/you/usr/local/OpenBLAS` (assuming the value of `$HOME` is `/home/you`) to create the destination directory.

Comment: NO,even if I change,I have this:make PREFIX=$/usr/local/OpenBLAS install
make -j 2 -f Makefile.install install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/milenko/OpenBLAS'
Generating openblas_config.h in usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Generating f77blas.h in usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Generating cblas.h in usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Copying LAPACKE header files to usr/local/OpenBLAS/include
Copying the static library to usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib
Copying the shared library to usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib
Generating OpenBLASConfig.cmake in usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib/cmake/openblas
Install OK!

Comment: But it is empty again!